# Android - Layout xml in layout-land is not loading when the device changes orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape

I am working on an Android project for my CS class where I need to enter mock coordinates. I want to specify a different layout file for orientation and portrait orientations. I have a `layout` folder and a `layout-land` folder in my `/res` folder. The xml file in the layout folder and the xml file in the layout-land folder are named exactly the same. I do NOT have `android:configChanges="orientation"` or `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` set for this specific activity - however, I do have it set for other activities. I am not implementing `onConfigurationChanged` in this activity either.

Theoretically, the screen should change to the layout specified in `layout-land` when the orientation changes with these settings, correct?

However, this is not the case. The layout stays the same.

I attempted to force it to change by giving the landscape layout a different layout id, `android:id="@+layout/activity_mock_coor_land"`, then doing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_mock_coor_land)"`.

However, it gave me an error with this stack trace:

```
AndroidRuntime(13964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(13964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mixd.grounds.tour/com.mixd.grounds.tour.MockCoor}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030009 type #0x12 is not valid
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(13964): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030009 type #0x12 is not valid
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at com.mixd.grounds.tour.MockCoor.onCreate(MockCoor.java:21)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
AndroidRuntime(13964):  ... 11 more
```

I'm not really sure what it means. Can it not find my layout in `layout-land`?

Can anyone help with this problem?

EDIT: Manifest:

> `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.mixd.grounds.tour"
>       android:versionCode="1"
>       android:versionName="1.0" >`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Choice"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choice"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MockCoor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mock_coor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MockActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mock"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NextCoor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_next_coor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryButton"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_button" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayHistory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_history" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> `</manifest>`

Comment: "Theoretically, the screen should change to the layout specified in layout-land when the orientation changes with these settings, correct?" Yes, but obviously something is awry. Please post your manifest.

Comment: Done! I meant to put it up before. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use a new name for your layout file you would need to rebuild everything from scratch meaning youd have to manully recreate everything including all your views. When using the layout-land you have to keep the same naming convention for everything. If you post all of your code we might be able to help you out but definitely dont use the land file with newly named files as you will have to rebuild the entire activity in a config changed.

Comment: I only renamed it once to force it to change. I had them set as the exact same name when I first tried it. I changed it back whenever I tested it with the orientation change.

Comment: Is there any real differences in the two layouts?

Comment: Not really. I adjusted the position of a couple of TextViews and a Button so that they were all visible. Originally, the TextViews would cover up the button. Small, but necessary change. I could limit the orientation to portrait, but I wanted to allow the physical keyboard to be used.

Comment: Try putting a statement in your onresume to check which orientation your in and print it to your logcat. Also what type of device are tou testing on

Comment: How would you get the current orientation? It's some old Motorola Droid that the CS department gave me. It runs 2.2.1.

Comment: Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Comment: It's printing 1, even when I switch orientations, meaning it's always in portrait mode. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I figured it might be doing that. Try checking the devices settings to see if its not allowing automatic orientation changes.

Comment: I'm don't think it's that? Orientation change works with other activities in the same app. EDIT: Auto-rotate screen is on.

Comment: If you keep running into a wall with this you could always put a statement in your on resume to test if its in portrait to switch to land and vice versa.

Comment: I don't want it to change the first time it loads. So I'd probably do that in onConfigurationChanged. I just wish I knew what the problem was.

Comment: It may be an issue with your style your using but without seeing all your code I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have the 'automatic rotation' function enable in your device.
In my device (Galaxy Gio) I can enable it on the notification window...